# Random number generator in C not accepting input for play again?

Tags: c, random

it works until it asks the user to play again. It will prompt the user but automatically quit and go back to the command line. can somebody tell me what's going on? it doesn't give me any warnings and i can't think of a reason why, i've tried a few things. I'm new to C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    char goAgain='y';
    int theNum=0;
    int guess=0;
    int max=0;
    do{
        do{
            printf("Enter a number over 99: ");
            scanf("%d", &max);
            if(max <= 99) {
                printf("Please enter a number over 99");
            }
        }while(max <= 99);
        srand(time(NULL));
        theNum = (rand() % max) + 1;
        do{
            printf("Please enter a guess:\n ");
            scanf("%d", &guess);
            if(guess > theNum) {
                printf("Too high\n");
            }
            else if(guess < theNum) {
                printf("Too high\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("That's correct!\n");
            }
        }while(theNum != guess);

        printf("Would you like to play again? (y/n): ");
        scanf("%c", &goAgain);
    }while(goAgain == 'y');
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You might need to flush the input stream.

Comment: i thought scanf didn't need a flush. Should i flush it before the scanf for "play again"?

Comment: Yes just make sure, sometime this can be a problem especially when you are reading chars.

Comment: No, scanf is input and fflush(stdin) is specifically stated in the C standard as undefined behaviour.   the returned value from scanf needs to be checked to assure the input/convert operation was successful .  Which would also have caught the main reason the code is failing.  Note: when inputting a char 'y' should also allow for 'Y' (capital).

Comment: Unrelated: Take this `srand(time(NULL));` **out** of your loops. Unless you're purposely regenerating a known-seed sequence, it should only be called *once* in your program, traditionally near the start of `main()`.

Comment: the inner do-while loop could run forever, suggest limiting the number of guesses.

Comment: Also you might be better if with getchar()

Comment: this code block: 'else if(guess < theNum) {
                printf("Too high\n");' is saying the wrong thing, suggest: printf("Too low\n");

Comment: well now when i input something it gives me "too high" every time no matter what. i put a while(getchar() != "\n"); before the scan f to make sure it's flushed

Comment: for good programing practice, this line: 'printf("Please enter a guess:\n ");' should also indicate the bounds of a valid guess, (note 0 is not a valid guess nor is any negative number.)

Comment: alright guys thanks a lot i got it working.. just one question how do you exit a loop in c? i'd like to limit the number of guess so i'd guess i'd make a counter variable and check the counter at the beginning of each loop but how would i make it exit? just return; like in java?

Comment: @user3242445 since you have a condition within `do ..while(goAgain == 'y' && cnt < <predefined value>)` So you can add one more check to the existing condition and yes you are right you need to keep the counter and that counter needs to be checked as shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%c", &goAgain);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c", &goAgain);
```

Note the space before `%c` which ignores the newline character (and any other white space).

There is a newline character when scanning an integer and that is being consumed by your `scanf("%c",&goAgain);` so please make sure you ignore it by placing a space before the format specifier `%c`.